# grid view of selected contact names and icons

Tags: android, gridview

I want a user to select some contacts from the contact list and then these selected contact names along with there photos  will be displayed in the grid view . can any one help

Comment: add a filter on your contact list, as user selects add them in another list(array) and then make grid using recycler view or gridview using custom layout.